# How do I get the List REST method to return the results with the display name and not the internal name

Tags: rest, odata

`zopv` & `s2u2` are internal names, but I would like the results to be returned using the display name.

> FileSystemObjectType: 0
>  Id: 2
>  ContentTypeId:
>   "0x010100517BCCBD1C63034A8C1141184DAB12C5"
>  Title: null
>   OData__dlc_DocId: null
>  OData__dlc_DocIdUrl: null
>  zopv: "Paint
>   Specification"
>  s2ue: "J"

Comment: The data is provided by SharePoint REST API and hence we can't control the names. Why can't you query the list information and get the display names first?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there will be a way to do it all in one call, but you don't need to make a call for each field, you could just make one extra call

```
http://<site>/_api/web/lists('<guid>')/fields?$select=Title,InternalName
```

And use that to create a lookup/mapping. Since those names aren't likely to change a lot (I would imagine) you could then store that information with `sessonStorage` to speed it up after the first request. I'm assuming the user might be browsing around your site or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Using REST API query the list information.

```
http://<site url>/_api/web/lists(guid'')/fields/getbyinternalnameortitle('zopv')
http://<site url>/_api/web/lists(guid'')/fields/getbyinternalnameortitle('s2u2')
```

This will give you the field information and use `Title` to get the display name

Comment: We'd prefer to make a single call. It's too bad their REST Api doesn't return the data in the same format as their WCF service, which uses the Display Name and not Internal Name.

Comment: @Edmond can you update the question with the REST URL format

Comment: http://<site url>/_api/web/lists(guid'e276c90b-618c-4315-8b9b-c3583b8e1930')/Items